# how to compare parent field to embedded field in mongodb (mongoose )

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongoose-schema

this is my schema i used embedded "comments" schema. my parent schema is "blogpost".

[image]

i just want to return only those documents which has like (in comments collection) are greater than likes (in blogpost collection)

[image]

please provide me code so i can return only those documents which contain like greater than likes (outer)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question (+ possibly format with the code format tool)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.